# Is there a term for an infographic appearing to give numeric information but not doing so?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

In an infographic at http://mobile.abc.net.au/news/2016-05-11/fact-check-negative-gearing-kelly-odwyer/7401096, there's a display of what proportion of various professions use negative gearing. At first I assumed the height of each individual indicated how much negative gearing they do, but their height increases by a regular amount instead. Is there a term for that, so you could say

> That infographic was a bit of a ____

Comment: First of all, the location of those individuals and the height at which they are placed is by design, so thay there would be enough room for the logo at the bottom right. Now, do you want a term that would mean an infograph that fails to do its job?

Comment: They are just placed in ascending order in a diagrammatic fashion.  The only difference in the height of the individuals is whether or not they are wearing a cap of some sort!

Comment: The title of this blog might count (warning: abbreviation of strong language): http://viz.wtf

Comment: An infographic brings you to a false conclusion (which is what you described) would probably be called **misleading**. Of course this isn't restricted to being "quantitatively/numerically misleading," which you specifically ask about in your question, though "misleading" is often used when talking about statistical distortion.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen the term "***not to scale***" used in such instances.

Like:

> That infographic was *not to scale*.

I could not find any proper references except **[this in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTS)**:

> **Not To Scale**, a disclaimer used in engineering drawings or schematics when the dimensions of the represented elements are not
>   proportionately accurate.